# What is the female version of "phallic"?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-positive

What is the female version of "phallic"?

> phal·lic/ˈfalik/Adjective
>
> 1. Of, relating to, or resembling a phallus or erect penis.

It would have a definition as:

> Of, relating to, or resembling a vagina.

Comment: Perhaps women are not so neatly summed up.

Comment: @jgbelacqua: ...or perhaps men don't build buildings so often needing resembling much else.

Comment: I believe the feminine for *phallic* really ought to be *phalliquette*. :)

Comment: Phalliquette, I like. @tchrist, I'm sure it would raise some fairly vehement opposition from the feminists... good for a laugh.

Comment: @tchrist that sounds phallacious.

Comment: You might say that the "female" version of "phallic" is "phallic". ;-) But there is **no** female or male version of "phallic". There is just "phallic" - the word has no gender (let alone sex).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think @canadiancreed/Merriam-webster's *yonic* is a bit quaint. It certainly has a longer history, but that may be because its ancient Sanskrit origins give it a certain air of respectability. ***Vulvic*** is [more common today](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vulvic,yonic&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3), perhaps because we live in an age that doesn't pussy-foot around delicate subjects quite so much (if you'll pardon the [double-entendres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_entendre)).

But if we were to allow whimsical neologisms, I'd have to go for *male:**phallic** = female:**phannic*** (which works better for Brits, since our *fanny* is always a [front bottom](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/front_bottom), not a backside).

Comment: +1: *yonic* is properly the opposite of *lingamic* anyway.

Comment: What happened in 1991 to make "yonic" so popular?

Comment: @user744: Doubtless nothing in particular. Quite a few of the occurrences counted by Ngram are misreadings (of *baryonic*, for example), and there aren't that many in total anyway. Just goes to show you can't read too much into automated analysis at this level.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happened to plain old *vaginal*?

Comment: "quaint" is a rather interesting choice of adjective here...

Comment: @T.E.D.: Mostly I just like the word (*quaint*, not *yonic*). I meant it's a bit "sub-culture", in that I associate it with slightly daffy middle-aged lesbians who were into flower-power and eastern mysticism back in the 60s when the rest of us were doing the sex, drugs, and rock&roll. I know that's a terrible stereotype, and I'm certainly not going to try to defend it - just being honest! :)

Comment: @onomatomaniak, that remains the opposite of *penile* rather than *phallic.*

Comment: Amusingly, I work with a gentleman whose name is Mahallingham. I'll leave that for you to figure out the meaning of.

Comment: re: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19171/what-is-the-female-version-of-phallic#comment86009_19176 Vaginal would be the opposite of Penile. Referring directly to the genitals themselves in common usage. Eg "his infection was penile" or "her infection was vaginal." Whereas one would say "what a phallic sculpture" not "what a penile sculpture."

Answer (score 8):

According to Merriam-webster, that would be the term [yonic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yonic?show=0&t=1301801822).

Comment: Of which the opposite is lingamic. It's not a clear antonym, though it would certainly serve.

Answer (score 1):

*Pudendal* is the adjective version of *pudenda*, which means the external genital organs, especially of a woman.

Comment: especially maybe but not absolutely restricted.

Answer (score 1):

Lingam is Sanskrit and so is Yoni. Besides meaning male and female genitals, they represent represent spiritual concepts such as 'male' and 'female' aspect of godhead. If 'yonic' is female, then 'lingamic' if I can say so, is the male version. We have to look for or coin one for phallic.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. Was it intended to be a comment? (Comments require a certain level of reputation, but answers in the "Your answer" box must be answers)

Answer (score 0):

The word *labial* might work, depending on what you are trying to convey.

Answer (score 0):

A quick stop by anatomy informs that [the female homologue to the male phallus (penis) is the clitoris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_related_male_and_female_reproductive_organs).

*Phallic* comes from the Ancient Greek *phallos* [by way of Late Latin *phallus*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/phallus).

Conveniently, *clitoral* comes from the Ancient Greek *kleitoris*, also [by way of Late Latin](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/clitoris).

By this deduction, the female analog to **phallic** is **clitoral**.

Answer (score -2):

I just spontaneously uttered "cunial" after cunnus, cunt, cunnilingus, etc. It's not a known word in a dictionary but that's true of all words at some point.

Answer (score -4):

How about 'Vulvic' or 'vulvate'?

Comment: I posted *vulvic* almost three years ago, and I'm far from convinced *vulvate* is really a valid word. It appears in some dictionaries, but not all (it's not in OED, for example).

Comment: As I was reading some literature on phallic celebrations, I happened to read the opposite of it which was clearly YONIC. Yoni is the Sanskrit (as well as many Indian language's) word for female sex organ.